# Masking site's domain: Is it making it slower?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, openshift, forwarding, domain-masking

I own a domain in godaddy (rainychat.com), and i have a node/socket.io chat app hosted in openshift on a domain provided by them (rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com)

I'm using "forwarding with masking" configuration on godaddy to make it so when a user enters rainychat.com, godaddy forwards the user to rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com, but with the user seeing rainychat.com in the browser (You can try that now if you want).

[image: Forwarding config]
My question is: As this is a chat app, is the user constantly going through godaddy first to reach my app because of the masking? I don't want my app to be slower because of this configuration. Is this the correct way to permanently direct a user to the site while still showing rainychat.com in the browser, or should i mess with DNS registery? Can i use .htaccess maybe?

Comment: Yes, this is most likely a "reverse proxy" which publishes the content "through" your frontend server. This is indeed an extra step, or hop from a network point of view. But typically the difference should be extremely small, I would not bother about that too much.

Comment: How would i go to avoiding the extra step? I'd like to avoid any delay if possible

Comment: Then you cannot use the proxy step. That would be possible if you operate the systems yourself, since you can then alter the host definitions. But such thing is impossible if you are just using a hosting provider. Then you have to play to his rules. So you end with your users not getting shown your domain, but a generic domain name of the hoster, if that is possible at all.

Comment: I'm currently trying to set this up as well for my OS app. I set up a cname record and sort of got it working.  However,  I now get a ssl cert error because I'm on a free account.  I could upgrade but won't for now. Do you have your own ssl cert? I switched back to forwarding now.

Comment: No ssl, sorry. So, which is better? 1) Forwarding with masking. 2) Forwarding + .htaccess file for the masking. 3) Mess with DNS records directly

Comment: Like I said, Im right in the process now.  I just switched to forwarding with masking but getting an error from OS.  Everytime I make a change it takes about 30 minutes to take affect.  Very slow going.  I don't think your #3 is going to give you desirable results with an ssl cert.

Comment: My forwarding with masking just updated and works now. I am going to try an experiment and see if I can get the cname working without an ssl cert next

Comment: To clarify,  I can get the cname working but chrome gives and cert error when visiting my OS app. Looks bad and scary for people to visit and trust.  I will see if I can work around it and report back.